# Drupal 6 & Ubercart 2 - Searching within attribute ranges on

Tags: drupal, search, range, ubercart

I am building a site where customers can order locks & keys based on their code.

Ideally we'd have a system where customers can search the code i.e FKC 348 and then drupal/ubercart brings up the group that its in (FKC 1 - 15000) with an option to add to cart along with the specific code they've entered.

I have looked at the 'search within range' modules & patches but they seem to mainly deal with pricing. Can I use CCK to create 'from' and 'to' fields combined with views filtering to provide this functionality? or would I be looking at a custom module/coding?

There are around 400 groups and 3million individual codes so adding each as attributes or tags is a no go.

Any help or pointers are most welcome, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use faceted search or  solr search. Faceted search may be your call because you data is not that much and also faceted search provides you with category search, taxonomy based search and also on attributes/fields search.

You can use  ubercart's product SKU field to search as SKU may represent your product unique code.

Hope this helps.